# What Type of Framework/Project is ideal for a Worker Program on a dedicated Windows Server

Tags: c#, .net, windows, http, frameworks

I want to build an application which runs on a dedicated windows server, receives web requests containing 'requested operations' (from a separate ASP.NET Core web application), and builds a task queue of these 'requested operations'. These 'requested operations' must be processed sequentially in a Task Queue on the main thread of the windows server program & return the response data to the ASP.NET core application.

Data will include generated files.

Would a .NET application such as a WPF app or Windows Forms app using an HttpListener to receive requests, a Task Queue system to manage the sequential processing & a HttpClient to generate responses be reasonable for this purpose?

Basically I am looking to be pointed in the general direction of these concepts & understand what approaches can be implemented for these kinds of requirements.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build two separate applications, a web application that receives HTTP requests, and a background worker application that processes items in the queue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-aspnet-core?view=vs-2022

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/workers?pivots=dotnet-8-0

The reasoning is the ASP.NET app will do a lot of heavy lifting for you to handle web requests. The worker app is also meant to run continuously, it can long-poll the queue, and process everything one at a time. You can also make HTTP requests to an API via the async worker.

Comment: It seems as though the correct configuration here is with the BackgroundService existing within the ASP.NET Core web application project, & being injected into the application through the builder.Services.AddHostedServices<ServiceA>

Does that track?

Comment: Yes, the background worker can run in the same process as the web app. The only reason I brought up having two separate services was to make it a bit more resilient. If the web app service crashes, for example, it won't inadvertently affect your background processor. It really all depends on what scale you are going for.